Have the effects of hydroalcoholic gel on mosquitos have been studied?
It is well known that alcohol attracts mosquitoes [1] and the impact of alcohol in the blood sucked by these insects is very low on their nervous system:

But in reality, insects can be remarkably resilient to the effects of alcohol [2].


So it is likely the alcohol is neutralised before it hits the insect’s nervous system [2].

[1] https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/12083361/
[2] https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20190313-will-mosquitoes-bite-me-more-when-ive-been-drinking
However, does the impact of hydroalcoholic gel on mosquitos has been studied? On my own (home-made) experience, several mosquitoes have resisted several hours in a closed box, but only few minutes once a piece of paper with some drops of hydroalcoholic gel has been introduced in the box...
Are they dying only because alcool has been breathed instead of sucked?

Have you thought about the concentration of blood alcohol much?

Welcome to SE Biology. It would help preserve the professional ethos of this site if you could edit your title so that it reads as grammatical English. Hint: replace “do” by the later “have”.

@David, thanks! Sure, I have edited the title.

When you say "hydroalcoholic gel" - are you referring to ethanol-based products or rather some other alcohol (eg. isopropanol)?

@JiminyCricket, I am speaking about hand sanitizer typically used during the COVID period and largely available in public shops (ethanol-based product)
